# QTableView does not show up

Tags: c++, qt

I have a widget (mainWindow) in which there is a dockWidget ( the one whose code is right below ).

The dock widget does show up. But not the tableView inside it. I also tried to force in the client widget constructor: "this->setWidget(ui->tableView)".

here "model" is a  QSqlRelationalTableModel which is a private member of the class.

clientWidget.cpp

```
#include "clientwidget.h"
#include "ui_clientwidget.h"
#include "dbwrapper.h"

clientWidget::clientWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QDockWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::clientWidget),
    model(this,dbWrapper::getInstance()->getDb())
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    model.setTable("Client");
    model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
    model.setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("id"));
    model.setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("Name"));
    model.setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("Zipcode"));
    model.setHeaderData(3, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("Country"));

    model.setHeaderData(4, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("phone"));

    model.setHeaderData(5, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("fax"));
    model.setHeaderData(6, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("email"));
    model.setHeaderData(7, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("taxId"));

    model.select();
    ui->tableView->setModel(&model);
}

clientWidget::~clientWidget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

While the setupUI looks like this:

```
void setupUi(QDockWidget *clientWidget)
{
    if (clientWidget->objectName().isEmpty())
        clientWidget->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("clientWidget"));
    clientWidget->resize(616, 406);
    dockWidgetContents = new QWidget();
    dockWidgetContents->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("dockWidgetContents"));
    tableView = new QTableView(dockWidgetContents);
    tableView->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("tableView"));
    tableView->setGeometry(QRect(5, 231, 601, 141));
    QSizePolicy sizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1);
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(1);
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(tableView->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
    tableView->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);
    clientWidget->setWidget(dockWidgetContents);

    retranslateUi(clientWidget);

    QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(clientWidget);
} // setupUi
```

I'm totally new too Qt GUI stuffs. Any idea would be welcome.

**EDIT:**

i've tried to add many combination of the following lines at the end of the constructor:

```
    ui->tableView->setModel(&model);
    this->setWidget(ui->tableView);
    this->ui->tableView->show();
    this->show();
```

**EDIT SOLUTION:**

problem lied completely elsewhere: My sqlite database did not contain the requested table. This is weird I thought that copy/paste an sqlite db file would compy the database ? The original one had the table in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See docs for `QDockWidget::setWidget`:

> If the dock widget is visible when widget is added, you must show() it explicitly.

It seems you need to add a line for showing:

```
clientWidget->setWidget(dockWidgetContents);
dockWidgetContents->show();
```

Comment: accepted for the sake of the effort and the accuracy of the comment anyway.